# auth:admin not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

i have created admin login system but on auth::attempt its always returning false
here is my code

```
$credentials= ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password'=>$request->get('password')]; 

   if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
          return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
   }
```

in Admin model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $primary_key = 'admin_id';
    protected $table = 'admins';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'admin_firstname', 'admin_lastname', 'email', 'admin_username', 'admin_phone', 'admin_picture', 'admin_gender', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
   }
```

in auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
```

auth::attempt is failing dont know why its not working

**its logging but problem is found in admin middleware 
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');**

my auth.php

```
 'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

],


 'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

degault guard is set as web but in dashboard controller i am using auth:admin please check

Comment: have you added provider also in auth.php  ?

Comment: yes i have added

Comment: can you update the question in your auth.php file

Answer (score 1):

your code looking like good.you need to make sure.did you use `bcrypt()` in registration.like this

```
$password=bcrypt($request['password']);
```

and you need to change in config/auth.php
your guard should be like this

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
```

and provider should be

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],


    ],
```

and password

```
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
        ],
    ],
```

this is demonstration change your model and driver accordingly

Comment: yes in database i am seeing my password encryptcted

Comment: post your auth.php and registration controller code

Comment: its logging correctly when i remove any middleware then its redirecting to dashboard

Comment: but when i add auth:admin then its redirecting to admin login

Comment: public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => ['logout']]);
    } add in admin login controller

Comment: did you add public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    } in dassboad controller

Comment: i am not getting any errors its redirecting backk to login

Comment: in app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php did you add public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
      switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
          if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
          }
          break;

        default:
          if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
              return redirect('/home');
          }
          break;
      }

      return $next($request);
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168794/discussion-between-rahul-shrivastava-and-pranav-mandlik).